# How to change background color of CupertinoAlertDialog?

Tags: flutter, dialog

I want create a CupertinoAlertDialog with dark background.

And I try to use Theme widget to solve this problem, but it doesn't work.

Some code here:

```
showDialog() {
    showCupertinoDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
                dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
                dialogTheme: DialogTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.black)),
            child: CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text('Title'),
            content: Text('Some message here'),
            actions: <Widget>[
               FlatButton(
                 onPressed: () {
                   Navigator.of(context).pop();
                 },
                 child: Text('OK'),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         );
       },
     );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using `Colors.black`, use `ThemeData.dark()`

```
showDialog() {
    showCupertinoDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData.dark(),
            child: CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text('Title'),
            content: Text('Some message here'),
            actions: <Widget>[
               FlatButton(
                 onPressed: () {
                   Navigator.of(context).pop();
                 },
                 child: Text('OK'),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         );
       },
     );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The background color is hardcoded:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/20e59316b8b8474554b38493b8ca888794b0234a/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/dialog.dart#L198

[image]

But you can create your own widget instead of default one.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use adaptive_ Dialog instead of it
https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_dialog

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Also read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This package is wrapper for `CupertinoAlertDialog` so... background color is hard coded.