# flutter: how can I adjust the property of CupertinoAlertDialog?

Tags: flutter

I'm new in flutter. I want to adjust the dimensions and other properties like background color of the CupertinoAlertDialog. I have searched in the documents and tried some properties but didn't work. For background color example, I have tried to put it into a `Container` and set its color. Definitely it didn't work. So how can I achieve it? Thanks in advance.
[image]

```
Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text('dropOut'), //对话框标题
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          
        ),
        actions: [
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            child: Text('cancel'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

**Edited:** I tried the method suggested by @Salim Murshed, but it didn't seem work so well. here is my code and the display!

```
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Pick Me !!!"),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (_) => Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 270, height: 140,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: CupertinoAlertDialog (
                      title: new Text("Material Dialog"),
                      content: new Text("Hey! I'm Coflutter!"),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text('Close me!'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(_);
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
          },
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You may need to use showdialog alertbox.

Comment: thanks for your advice. Could I bother you to give me a small example, please? I have searched it but still not clear about it.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57676581/5362583

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below code.

```
RaisedButton(
    child: Text("Pick Me !!!"),
    onPressed: () {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
                title: new Text("Material Dialog"),
                content: new Text("Hey! I'm Coflutter!"),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Close me!'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(_);
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ));
    },
  )
```

Comment: yes bro, you show a good dialog for me. But what I want is a CupertinoAlertDialog(iOS style). I want change its background color and dimension. Anyway thank you so much.

Comment: Change the alertdialog to cupertinoalert dialog and set parent container then.

Comment: I have tried your method but it didn't seem to be so good. Could you please take a look? Thank you very much.